# Outlook 2016 keeps crashing

Tags: exchange, kernel, microsoft-outlook-2016, event-viewer

My Outlook 2016 Exchange does not start. I go to open, the flash screen appears and then I get a message asking if I want to start in safe mode. Whether I answer yes or no it does not matter, it just crashes.

I have tried repairing .pst file and repairing the office installation. I completely re-installed office and the problem came back after a few days.

This is what appears in Event Viewer when I try to open:

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.7870.2024, time stamp: 0x58bf8d83
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23677, time stamp: 0x589c9620
Exception code: 0xe06d7363
Fault offset: 0x0000c54f
Faulting process id: 0x5b4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2a2670713cef3
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 474ca6fc-0e5a-11e7-a7aa-f04da2cc4d7c
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Exchange 2016 is crashing or Outlook 2016 is crashing?  There is a huge difference

Comment: Outlook 2016. Sorry for the confusion @Ramhound

Answer (score 2):

This has been solved. I created a new profile and it solved the issue. Thank you to those who commented and viewed.